# What Windows Cache File Stores Taskbar Thumbnail Previews (Image when Hovering Mouse over Taskbar)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, images, taskbar, cache

I am interested in determining where Windows saves the taskbar previews that it displays when you hover your mouse over an application on the taskbar; for example:

[image]
or
[image]

I tried using Thumbcache Viewer to view all of the .db files located at this directory: `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`,
but those files only seemed to contain caches for image files (pngs and jpgs), folder previews, or application icons. I was not able to find any of the taskbar previews in any of the files in the following list:

[image]

Are they stored in a different location? Or did I just miss them?

Comment: None of them. They are an image of the application that is currently running

Comment: @Mokubai, so where are those images stored? Or are they not at all?

Comment: The are not stored at all. They are simply a scaled down copy of currently rendered window. Notice how the contents of that thumbnail change rapidly. Icons are cached because it means going to one individual file instead of opening and searching through hundreds of different DLL files where they might be stored. These preview images don't need to be cached elsewhere because they are already drawn by the GPU and the desktop window manager and just need a simple scale down (in memory) to be shown on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Since an application can *change* the taskbar icon. and caption, while running, I don't think Windows caches them. For example, below, note that the icon for MPC-HC changes according to the application state: paused or running.

[image: Taskbar Icon Update]

Because the application continually updates the icon and text, there would not be much point to long-term caching.